# DE10-Lite VGA Controller Display

Tags: fpga, vga, imageprocessing

this is my design: https://github.com/Shehab-Hesham/FPGA_IP_VGA/tree/main.

On an oscilloscope, the vertical sync and horizontal sync are correctly given as output; however, the color channels output 0 always, why can that be?

I am using a DE10-Lite board that has a MAX10 FPGA mounted on it, 10M50DAF484C7G. The simulation is working fine, and the colors are being shown as output, but on hardware, it shows a black screen regardless of the image.

The RGB pins are not giving any outputs; however, the sync pulses are correct. The simulation results are correct.

Comment: You've asked: "I have this project. Please fix the problems for me." Is there anything you know about the problems that could narrow down where the problems are?

Comment: what's it not doing.  no sync? no R,G,B? wrong sync frequency?

Comment: No RGB, sync is fine on oscilloscope

Comment: Line 179 of `hardware.v` - you drive the reset pin from a register that is never assigned a value.

Comment: Fixed, but why would it affect the performance?

Comment: Are you asking why the unit held in reset does not produce any values?